# how do I get backslashed escaped version of a glob expression in python3

Tags: python, escaping, glob, pathname

I am building commands in Python, including a glob expression that also contain whitespace characters.

I read that the suggested way is using *shlex.quote*, but it only works for actual resoved pathnames, because enclosing the expression within `'` or `"` also blocks the shell *glob expansion*.

### Simplest possible example:

```
touch 'a file.txt'
ls 'a file.*' # this gives an error because the glob is not resolved
# shlex.quote achieves the same result
python3 -c "import os; from shlex import quote; os.system('ls '+quote('a file.*'))"    
ls a\ file.* # this is what I need
```

I know that I can use any replacement technique to replace spaces `' '` with `'\ '` in that string (e.g. regexps to name one), but I thought that should there already exist a suitable function, I should first look for it rather than writing my own code...

### The real case

The commands I am composing, should affect multiple files whose pathname is like (think of it separated by underscores `'_'`):

```
dir/WrongID_Another ID With Spaces_other-stuff-with-hyphens.bmp
```

I want to obtain commands like:

```
rename "s/^WrongID_/RightId_/" dir/WrongID_Another\ ID\ With\ Spaces_*.*
```

... where `dir`, `WrongID`, `Another ID With Spaces`, `RightID`, are read from a table

Many such commands are written to a single file, a script which I will then feed to bash.

Comment: Using Python to run a Bash command to drive a Perl tool, are we...? Bash already provides `printf "%q"` for this use case, though really, I guess you simply need to get the Bash quoting right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for

```
while read -p dir wrong rest right; do
    rename "s/^${wrong}_/${right}_/" "$dir/${wrong}_${rest}_"*.*
done <<\____
    one    few     other   many
    two    theyre  stuff   there
    three  grammer correct grammar
____
```

The braces are necessary to disambiguate `${wrong}_` (the variable `wrong` followed by an underscore) from `$wrong_` (the variable `wrong_` with an underscore).

I don't think Python is necessary or useful here, though as you have found, `shlex.quote()` does provide the functionality you are asking for.  If you want to drive this from Python, it's much better to avoid the shell entirely.

```
import subprocess
import glob

for dir, wrong, rest, right in (
        ('one',   'few',     'other',   'many'),
        ('two',   'theyre',  'stuff',   'there'),
        ('three', 'grammer', 'correct', 'grammar')):
    subprocess.run(['rename', 's/^{0}_/{1}_/'.format(wrong, right)] +
        glob.glob('{0}/{1}_{2}_*.*'.format(dir, wrong, rest))])
```